# Android App: Press a button and open a new layout

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a beginner developer and I am making an Android app. 
I made a layout and I called it activity_stats and I want to open
the layout (layout name: youtubestats) when I press the button called Channel Stats.

Activity_Main:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Go to the GoldenNuggetNL channel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox1"
        android:text="Go to the Website of GoldenNuggetNL" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox2"
        android:text="Watch latest video" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox3"
        android:text="Contact" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox4"
        android:text="Rate app" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/checkBox6"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/checkBox5"
        android:text="Channel stats" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Run selected objects" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:onClick="sendMessage"
        android:text="Quit" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation here explains it pretty well:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html

The basics are that you need to create an onclick handler for your button (which you can do either in the XML file using [android:onClick](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#attr_android:onClick) or in your Java code by calling the [setOnClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener(android.view.View.OnClickListener)) method), and then in the handler for your click, you need to use an [intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) to activate the second [activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html).

Note that such an intent would need to be listed in the set of [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html)s for that activity so that the activity responds to that particular intent.

If you want to show a layout within the current activity instead of opening a new activity, then you can simply call [setContentView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Window.html#setContentView(int)) or inflate a [ViewStub](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html) in the current activity.